# Application -defined or object - defined error referring to Excel Cells in Outlook VBA

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

Below is code I have written to automate sending meeting invites.

The code picks content from cells in sheet: Final_List.

I have highlighted where I'm getting an error when I try get the recipient address from Excel

> Application -defined or object - defined error.

```
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outlookmeet As AppointmentItem
Dim myRequiredAttendee As Recipient

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim RowCount As Long

RowCount = 2
'row 1 has headers

With Worksheets("Final_List")

    Do While IsEmpty(Cells(RowCount, 1).Value) = False

        Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set outlookmeet = outlookApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
        With outlookmeet

            .MeetingStatus = olMeeting

            .Subject = Cells(RowCount, 1).Value & " - " & Cells(RowCount, 2).Value
            .Location = Cells(RowCount, 3).Value
            .Start = Cells(RowCount, 5).Value
            .Duration = Cells(RowCount, 7).Value

            'getting errors on this line                     
            .Recipients.Add (Cells(RowCount, 6).Value)

            .Recipients.ResolveAll

            .Body = Cells(RowCount, 4).Value
            .Send
        End With

        RowCount = RowCount + 1

    Loop
End With

Set outlookmeet = Nothing
Set outlookApp = Nothing
MsgBox "All invites sent!"
```

Comment: You have two nested `With` statements, meaning all the cell addresses in the inner `With` statement are on the currently active sheet, which may or may not be "Final_List".

Comment: @Variatus: I can activate the "Final_List" sheet. But I'm not able to add recipients in the invite? Any help for this point?

Comment: The AppointmentItem object doesn't have a `Recipient` property. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210899(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: @variatus: any other method you can suggest?

Comment: got the issue resolved:

Answer (score 0):

The AppointmentItem object doesn't have a Recipient property. [Compare MSDN library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210899(v=office.11).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution:

```
Sub ScheduleMeeting()

    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim outlookmeet As Outlook.AppointmentItem

    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim Name1 As Variant

    RowCount = 2
    'row 1 has headers
    Worksheets("MeetingInvite").Activate

    With Worksheets("MeetingInvite")

        Do While IsEmpty(Cells(RowCount, 1).Value) = False

            Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set outlookmeet = outlookApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

            With outlookmeet

                .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
                .Subject = Cells(RowCount, 1).Value 
                .Location = Cells(RowCount, 2).Value
                .Start = Cells(RowCount, 4).Value
                .Duration = Cells(RowCount, 6).Value

                .RequiredAttendees = Cells(RowCount, 5).Value

                .Body = Cells(RowCount, 3).Value

                .Display

            End With

            RowCount = RowCount + 1

        Loop
    End With

    Set outlookmeet = Nothing
    Set outlookApp = Nothing
    'MsgBox "All invites sent!"

End Sub
```